# How can I solve this polynomial problem?

Tags: polynomials, homework

I'm very new to Mathematica.

> The only roots of a polynomial are 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. The polynomial is positive on (-∞, 1), (1, 2), (4, 5) and negative on (2, 3), (3, 4), and (5,  ∞). Give a polynomial of the smallest degree that satisfies these conditions. Make the leading coefficient 1 or -1.

Comment: You have posted multiple homework problems recently, without saying anything about what you did so far to try to solve them. Such questions are not acceptable on this site. If you truly have no idea where to start, then you must talk to your instructor. Otherwise, please ask about the specific point where you got stuck instead of posting the entire problem. Show what you did so far.

Comment: "I'm very new to Mathematica so I'm not familiar with the codes." Regarding this, a minimal familiarity with Mathematica is required before asking here. There are many tutorials. Please learn the basics. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18/12

Comment: My professor doesn't do lectures, he just gives us an example and a somewhat confusing book to go off of. I have corrected my other answers and you're right I  actually understand a little more than I thought. I just spend a long time trying to figure out what I'm missing like a = to make my code work so I come here to understand what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p[x_] = -(x - 1)^2 (x - 2) (x - 3)^2 (x - 4) (x - 5);
Plot[p[x], {x, 0.5, 5.2}, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]